# Resolving multiple versions of React in component library built with Webpack and Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, material-ui

I'm trying to build a React component library built on top of MUI and using Storybook and TypeScript. Because Storybook (which uses create-react-app) is based off of Webpack, and because my component library includes SASS files that can't be compiled using `tsc`, I'm using Webpack to build the bundle. Then I'm importing the component library into another React application, with its own version of React.

To test this out, I've built a vanilla TypeScript create-react-app demo app, and am importing my library from a specific branch on my hosted Github repo. When I try to include a component from the library, the TS types show up correctly, but the app throws [one of these errors](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), pointing to a use of hooks in the underlying MUI library. This seems overwhelmingly likely to me to be a competing-React-versions issue, rather than a hooks issue, because A) MUI works, and B) the components work within the Storybook.

Here's the basic structure of my component library.

I put app dependencies unrelated to build (React, MUI, MUI dependencies) in `peerDependencies`, so that they aren't duplicated.

#### Component Library

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "my-component-library",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
    // ...
  },
  // ... Lotsa devDependencies
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"
  }
}
```

**`webpack.config.js`**

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: "MyComponentLibrary",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    clean: true,
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        options: { configFile: "tsconfig.build.json" },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  target: "node",
};
```

**`tsconfig.build.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "outDir": "dist/types",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.tsx", "src/**/*.stories.tsx", "src/__mocks__"]
}
```

When I run `npm run build`, Webpack compiles the files into `dist/index.js` correctly, and the types are put (with a bunch of extraneous stuff I'd like to sort out) into `dist/types`.

#### Demo App

Then, my consuming demo app is a basic CRA application, with the TypeScript template. Here's the key components of the package file:

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "cld",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.27",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",

    // Note the Github require
    "my-component-library": "github:my-private-handle/component-library#branch"
  },
}
```

In my App.tsx file:

**`App.tsx`**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "my-component-library";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button>Hello</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I hover over `Button`, I see the component documentation, and if I give it bad props, TS shows the errors. But if I run the app, the file throws the above error because of mismatched React versions (I think).

However, there appears to correctly be only one version each of React and React DOM -- the one defined by the consuming app.

```
npm list react react-dom
cld@0.1.0 /Users/sasha/code/cld
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├── react@17.0.2
└─┬ my-component-library@0.1.0 (git+ssh://git@github.com/private-handle/component-library.git#09b5db39d8aa8a76f7c1fecacdc3afaecd57812e)
  ├─┬ @emotion/react@11.9.0
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @emotion/styled@11.8.1
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @mui/icons-material@5.6.1
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @mui/material@5.6.1
  │ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.76
  │ │ ├── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.6.1
  │ │ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.6.1
  │ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.6.1
  │ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.6.1
  │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ ├── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
  │ │ ├── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ react-router-dom@6.3.0
  │ ├── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ react-router@6.3.0
  │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  └── react@17.0.2 deduped
```

---

**UPDATE:** Following the debugging recommendations [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), I did this in the receiving/demo app:

```js
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

As of the latest run, this returns `false`, because `window.React1` is undefined -- and the local `node_modules/react-dom/index.js` file appears not to be hit despite the `require("react-dom")`. The result of that require **is** a ReactDOM object, so I'm not sure where it's coming from. Very strange, but probably the root of the issue.

---

**UPDATE:** I've validated that this is the only issue in the repo. Components that aren't built on MUI and don't use hooks (directly, or through MUI) render just fine. Utils exported from the same library work perfectly, as do the types. It's just that any component that uses MUI or another library using React hooks throws an error. This makes no sense to me, since there's one single version of React in the app.

Comment: Normally new versions of NPM should throw a warning (or error) about this. Your peer dep of ^17 should not work with the dep of ^18 in the demo app. Your demo app should either use react ^17 (since that's what your component library needs) or you should make your component library have a peer dep of `^17 || ^18` if you know either version should work

Comment: I updated the versions in the CL (see above) to accept >= 17. Still running into the same error, because it appears both React versions are being used.

Comment: make sure you're deleting the package-lock in both cases. Might be worth checking whether there's other deps that cause issues, e.g. if you only use `react-scripts` to build your CL you should move them to devDeps so they don't get resolved by NPM when installing your CL as a dep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem boiled down to this: Webpack was building a bundle **with** React, ReactDOM, and React Router. The versions of React etc within the bundle conflicted with the versions in the "receiving" app, *even though* `npm list` didn't show multiple versions.

To fix this, I used the [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) functionality in my webpack config:

```
{
  ...
  externals: {
    'react': 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    'react-router-dom': 'react-router-dom',
    'react-router': 'react-router'
  }
}
```

This then builds to a `dist` folder but does not include React etc in the build, instead expecting it to be installed in the receiving app. That build bundle is published. Currently, I'm just pulling it in from Github, but this should work released to NPM or a private package repository.

The consuming/receiving app can then import the files/types just fine, without clashes.

Comment: Thanks G. If anyone is using Rollup, the solution is the same: `external: ['react', 'react-dom'],`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when developing React component library.

The only solution that consistently worked for me was using relative npm link from the example folder to the webpack folder and forcing this specific version on the webpack project.
Reread the last lines of [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) section and try it out. Note that for me only npm link worked(yarn link did not)
Here's a real project that uses this method, and a script that handles it
https://github.com/Eliav2/react-xarrows/blob/197326ccb032d5b5a3a7e18def596abac7327b05/examples/package.json#L34.
Make sure to adjust the relative path to your case

(sorry for the format, answering from mobile device)

Another option is using monorepo,then a single copy of react will be installed and you could import your Lib from the examples project

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't rely on these apps being collocated structurally. They're separate apps, and the lib might be imported in many places. Also (see above) this isn't just an issue with local imports, as it also applies to installing it from Github. This seems to only apply as a solution to an app pulling in the lib dependency locally, no?

Comment: It's used for testing. When you will ship your Lib it would run over the local React on the client

Comment: So you stopped running into this issue once the package was built and deployed to npm etc? Per my edits above, I'm running into it even when I build it to Github and pull it from there. Makes me think maybe this *isn't* a different-react-version issue, but I don't see what else it could be, since the same components don't throw the error when they're rendered within the component library.

Comment: When you build your Lib, react should be external dependency and not be bundled, this way this won't be a duplicate versions of react error